# Expected conditions invisibilityof not working

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to wait untile the element to be invisible, but getting exception even the element is invisible.
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOf(WebElement));

Comment: Please show the code and also the website link if possible

Comment: String Validationtext = test.validation_message().getText();
   if (Validationtext.contains("Invalid job number")) {
    System.out.println(jnum + " is invalid Job number");
     
       wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOf(test.validation_message()));
     
     return;
   }

Comment: I dont want to use Thread. sleep, if I use it's working fine.

Comment: @ramesh - please edit your question. Show us the full code you are using and the full error you get.